# Why safari hangs right after installation on Windows XP?

Tags: windows, safari, performance

I've just installed Safari on Windows XP SP3 and after succesful installation it starts and just hangs up. I also see process Webkit2Webprocess.exe which uses 100% of one core and nothing else happens.

Can you please give me some hints how to fix this?

Comment: Seems like everyone's having the problem with the latest Safari upgrade...

Comment: can you perhaps let us know if this is still an issue? Did you resolve it? Can you add more details so an answer might be provided for others?

Comment: There's a decent answer here and the OP could just uninstall Safari. Without more details, leaving this open for new answers doesn't seem to be warranted as it's not even clear what version of Safari is being installed at this late date.

Answer (score 1):

Safari hangs when it cannot find a network, like when you need to specify proxy settings. Try on a network that doesn't need a proxy; it will not hang there.

Comment: Can't reproduce this on the Macs here, is this a "behavior" specific to Windows?